# why can't I insert a 'cout' statemement here?

Tags: loops, nested

I hope you guys can bear with me because I'm new

I'm supposed to write a small program to output the multiplication table using nested loops.

Using the first code I wrote

```
int number = 1,order=0;
    for (cout << "Multiplication Table" << endl; number < 10; number++)
    {
        cout << number << "  ";
        order++;
        for (int number2 = 0,number = 1; (order > 8 && number < 10); number2++, number++)
        {
            cout << 2 * number << "  ";
        }
        
    }
```

The program does the job relatively well, although I want independent rows between each for loop so I just should add ' cout<<"\n" 'in the inner for loop as an initial-action right? well it doesn't work and give me errors like ' forget ; ' where ever I put it, Does any one know the cause of the problem?
This is how the inner for loop is supposed to look like, Thank you.

`for (cout<<"\n", int number2 = 0,number = 1; (order > 8 && number < 10); number2++, number++)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop initialization has to be a single statement. While it's possible, thanks to syntax conveniences, to declare and initialize more than one **int** in a statement, you cannot also execute the stream insertion in the same statement. The error message is complaining about the missing statement termination operator **;** between statements.

Also, let me recommend **std::endl** in place of **"\n"**. Get in that habit early and it will save you many hours of your life.

Comment: Oh okay I understand now thank you, and yeah I've heard a lot about std::endl I'll make sure to get used to it, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

cout << "      Multiplication Table" << endl;

```
for (int header = 1; header < 10; header++)
{
    cout << header << "   ";
}


for(int row = 2; row < 10; row++)
{
    cout  << endl;
    for (int order = 1; (order < 10); order++)
    {
        int product = row * order;
        
        cout << product << "  ";
        if(product < 10)
            cout << " ";
        
    }
}
```